# Can't load converted from FBX to JSON model using THREE.JSONLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I converted an FBX model to JSON using convert-to-threejs.py, but I can't get three.js (r58) to load it. It says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". The error is at line 9930 in three.js which line is `for ( i = 0; i < json.uvs.length; i++ ) ...`

Here's the converted JSON: http://pastebin.com/86ZGvKnW. You'll see that it does not, in fact, have a `uvs` property.

**Is convert-to-threejs.py outdated? If so, what's the alternative? If not, how can I get this model to load?**

Here's my code:

```
window.loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('jet.json', function(geometry) {
    // Never gets to here; error is thrown first
    console.log(geometry);
});
```

Comment: The updated python script is at https://github.com/zfedoran/convert-to-threejs-json

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see. The actual model is embedded in that JSON file. I want `embeds["Embed_31_jet 3"]`.

Answer (score 0):

FBX files converted to JSON seem to describe complete scenes. So, instead of `THREE.JSONLoader`, use [`THREE.SceneLoader`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/SceneLoader).

For example

```
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(...);

  var loader = new THREE.SceneLoader();
  loader.load('jet.json', function(res) {
      scene.add(res.scene);
      renderer.render(res.scene, camera);
  });
```